# data structure for multi-key data?

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, hashtable

is there a commonly used data structure for mult-key data? e.g. (key1, key2, ..., keyN) -> value. I used to use dictionaries of dictionaries (in c#), and then wrote my own wrapper on top of this to make the syntax look a bit nicer. but it seems like I still have to write a wrapper for each N-dictionary, where N is the number of keys, since I have to define the nested dictionary structure within the code.

assuming I'm using c#, is there a data structure that better encapsulates this sort of usage, and could contain an arbitrary number of keys with hashtable-like lookup performance? I can't simply combine all the keys into a single unique key, because I need to be able to do something like

```
foreach key2 in data[key1]
    foreach key3 in data[key1][key2]
        foreach key4 in data[key1][key2][key3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't.

Without breaking type-safety, I think there are two solutions.

- Dictionaries of Dictionaries - `Dictionary<T1, Dictionary<T2, TRes>>`
- Dictionaries of tuples - `Dictionary<Tuple3<T1, T2, T3>, Res>`. Note that - unlike F# where you could write `Map<T1 * T2 * T3, Res>` - C# doesn't have a builtin tuple type - you'd have to implement this separately as a generic class or struct.

But regarding your example code, jagged dictionaries (Dictionaries of Dictionaries) are the only alternative.

Comment: your first suggestion seems to be vastly superior to the first to in most cases.  It is an approach I find myself using alot.  I can't see the benefit of 3 keys if you're just going to use a tuple.  Other than that good suggestions.